# How to shadow existing variables when destructuring in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructuring, std-pair, structured-bindings

Is there any way to shadow existing variables when destructuring a `std::pair`? For example if I have the following functions defined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, int> returns_pair(int a, int b)
{
    return std::make_pair(a * a, b * b);
}

void prints_two_variables(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a << "\n" << b << "\n";
}
```

Then this `main` function works fine, since I make new variables from the returned `std::pair`:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    auto [x, y] = returns_pair(a, b);
    prints_two_variables(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 4
> 9
> ```

But I can't use the same variable names and shadow the existing variables, since this tries to actually declare them again:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    auto [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
    prints_two_variables(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

> Error:
>
> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:12:15: error: conflicting declaration ‘auto a’
>     auto [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
>               ^
> main.cpp:10:9: note: previous declaration as ‘int a’
>     int a = 2;
>         ^
> main.cpp:12:15: error: conflicting declaration ‘auto b’
>     auto [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
>               ^
> main.cpp:11:9: note: previous declaration as ‘int b’
>     int b = 3;
>         ^
> ```

I tried also without the `auto`, but that gave a totally different error:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
    prints_two_variables(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

> Error:
>
> ```
> main.cpp: In lambda function:
> main.cpp:12:12: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘=’ token
>     [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
>            ^
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:12:31: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘main()::’ and ‘std::pair’)
>     [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
>                               ^
> main.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: main()::& main()::::operator=(const main()::&) 
>     [a, b] = returns_pair(a, b);
>          ^
> main.cpp:12:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair’ to ‘const main()::&’
> ```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) be useful here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).  That will create a a `std::tuple` of references to the parameters and allow you to reassign the `pair` to the elements it was created from.  That would look like

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    std::tie(a, b) = returns_pair(a, b);
    prints_two_variables(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to also `#include` the `<tuple>` header so you can use `std::tie`.

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: This is not shadowing. This is re-assignment. It's equivalent to `a = a*a; b = b*b;`.

Comment: @KevinZ I never used the word shadowing.  In fact, I used reassigned: *That will create a a std::tuple of references to the parameters and allow you to **reassign** the pair to the elements it was created from.*

Comment: @KevinZ Yeah good call, I used the word shadowing too loosely, reassigning is completely fine also for me here.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there any way to destructure a pair, while shadowing existing variables?

No. A structured binding declaration always introduces identifiers, it cannot shadow or assign over existing variables. This is ill-formed:

```
int i = 4;
auto [i] = std::tuple(5);
```

for the same reason this is ill-formed:

```
int i = 4;
int i = 5;
```

If what you want to do is overwrite, you can use `tie` and assign:

```
std::tie(a, b) = returns_pair(a, b);
```

This works in this scenario, but not in the general case where `returns_pair` might return a struct with two public members.